# How can I fix my android emulator not starting?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm getting a warning printed to the console whenever I attempt to launch an emulator. The emulator never launches and the process just hangs.

```
./emulator -avd Pixel_4a_API_31 -verbose -show-kernel
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found AVD name 'Pixel_4a_API_31'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
VERBOSE |  Found directory: /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | emuDirName: '/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
INFO    | try dir /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path '/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
VERBOSE | Adding library search path for Qt: '/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
VERBOSE | Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
VERBOSE | Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
VERBOSE | Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
VERBOSE | Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
VERBOSE | Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
VERBOSE | emulator: Running :/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[00] = "/Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[02] = "Pixel_4a_API_31"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[04] = "-show-kernel"
VERBOSE | Concatenated backend parameters:  /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -avd Pixel_4a_API_31 -verbose -show-kernel
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skin pixel_4a
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skindir /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/skins/
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -kernel /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
VERBOSE | Target arch = 'x86_64'
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img
VERBOSE | Using initial system image: /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//system.img
VERBOSE | Using initial vendor image: /Users/jos76/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -data /Users/jos76/.android/avd/Pixel_4a_API_31.avd/userdata-qemu.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -initdata /Users/jos76/.android/avd/Pixel_4a_API_31.avd/userdata.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -cache /Users/jos76/.android/avd/Pixel_4a_API_31.avd/cache.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/jos76/.android/avd/Pixel_4a_API_31.avd/sdcard.img
VERBOSE | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
VERBOSE | VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
VERBOSE | System image is read only
VERBOSE | Found 1 DNS servers:
VERBOSE |   192.168.1.1
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
VERBOSE | Unexpected feature list:
VERBOSE | Vulkan
```

I'm currently using the latest version of the android emulator. I've attempted to search solutions online without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [wipe data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCXqM.png). All data will be cleared.